Solve scheduling model using a greedy heurisitc
I have the following scheduling problem. Relatively simple and not very complex (only serves as an example). The indexes are $I$ worker, $T$ days and $J$ shift. The decision variable is $x_{ijt}$, which is 1 if a person works a certain shift. I also have variables for udnerstaffing $u_{tj}$ and overstaffing $o_{jt}$. I have the parameters $D_{jt}$ demand. The goal is to minimize under and overstaffing. Since my whole model is very complex for large model instances, I would like to solve it with a greedy heuristic (on the advice of a colleague), but I am not familiar with the theory and especially with the implementation in Gurobi.
How would I suspend the theory and the implementation for a greedy heuristic for my model in Gurobi?
This is my model:
\begin{align}
&\min\sum_j\sum_t( o_{jt}+u_{jt})&\\
&\sum_i x_{ijt} + u_{jt}-o_{jt}=D_{jt}\quad&\forall j,t\\
&\sum_j x_{ijt}\leq 1\quad &\forall i,t\\
&x_{ijt}\in \left\{ 0,1 \right\}\quad &\forall i,t,j
\end{align}
The gurobi code is:
from gurobipy import *

# Create a new model
m = Model("Scheduling Problem")

# Define the indices
num_workers = 10
num_days = 5
num_shifts = 3
I = range(num_workers)  # Set of workers
T = range(num_days)     # Set of days
J = range(num_shifts)   # Set of shifts

# Define the demand parameter as a dictionary
D = {}
D[(0,0)] = 4
D[(0,1)] = 3
D[(0,2)] = 5
D[(0,3)] = 2
D[(0,4)] = 6
D[(1,0)] = 3
D[(1,1)] = 4
D[(1,2)] = 2
D[(1,3)] = 5
D[(1,4)] = 3
D[(2,0)] = 5
D[(2,1)] = 2
D[(2,2)] = 6
D[(2,3)] = 3
D[(2,4)] = 4

# Create the decision variables
x = m.addVars(I, J, T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
u = m.addVars(J, T, lb=0, name="u")
o = m.addVars(J, T, lb=0, name="o")

# Set the objective function
obj = quicksum(u[j,t] + o[j,t] for j in J for t in T)
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Add the constraints
for j in J:
    for t in T:
        m.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j,t] for i in I) + u[j,t] - o[j,t] == D[j,t])

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        m.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j,t] for j in J) <= 1)

# Solve the problem
m.optimize()


Are you looking for help with Gurobi (your code snippet seems to work fine) or for a greedy heuristic? Can you specify your question please.

Cross-posted here

I have two comments that might be related to the fact that your model is simplified. First, why do you need $o_{jt}$, since you dont require every person to work (Constraint 2), so this variable would always be 0. Second, wouldnt it be an optimal decision to just assign a random person to a task, until the demand is fulfilled?

You are right, these problems are due to the models simplicicty

In that case, you should add some of your model complexity to the question, such that the problem will be non-trivial to solve.
